# Setting or replacing values in a dataframe column based on other columns through a hash map

Tags: python, pandas

I need to set the values of a column in a dataframe based on other columns, through a hash map. I could not get it work through the existing answers. Hope some kind coder will help me.

I have a df with some columns. I want to add a new column, in which the values are based on some other existing columns. The value would be set based on a hash map.

This is the hash map, created from a dataframe; the index is a tuple:

```py
material_code_map = dict([((a,b,c),i) for i, a,b,c in zip(df.Material,
                                                          df.Height,
                                                          df.Pole_Class,
                                                          df.Treatment)])
```

Then I have a df that contains columns Material, Height, Pole_Class, etc.
In the df I want to add the column Material, where Material is derived from the map based on the tuple (Height, Pole_Class, Treatment).

The following test code does work:

```py
cleaned = cleaned.assign( Material_Number=lambda x: x.Pole_Class + x.Pole_Length )        
cleaned = cleaned.assign( Material_Number=lambda x: material_code_map[(30, 6, 'PENTA')] )
```

However this code, which seems the obvious next step, doesn't work:

```py
cleaned = cleaned.assign( Material_Number=lambda x: material_code_map[(x.Pole_Length, x.Pole_Class, 'PENTA')] )
```

I get the error:

```py
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Thanks for helping me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution and I share it here, in case it will be useful to others like me. 
I use a simpler code, to focus on the sintax. d is the mapping table (dictionary) and df is the table with columns A and B; column C is added with values based on A,B through the map d.

```py
In [12]: d
Out[12]: {(1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 3, (1, 4): 4}

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
      A     B
0     1     2
1    11    22
2     1     3
3  1111  2222

In [14]: df['C'] = df[['A','B']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(d)

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
      A     B    C
0     1     2  2.0
1    11    22  NaN
2     1     3  3.0
3  1111  2222  NaN
```

It also works with strings, as I need in my case:

```py
In [23]: d
Out[23]: {(1, 'a'): 1, (1, 'b'): 2, (1, 'c'): 3, (1, 'd'): 4}

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
      A     B
0     1     a
1    11    22
2     1     c
3  1111  2222

In [25]: df['C'] = df[['A','B']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(d)

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
      A     B    C
0     1     a  1.0
1    11    22  NaN
2     1     c  3.0
3  1111  2222  NaN

In [27]:
```